# Get number of days since epoch in C++ (cross platform)

Tags: c++, cross-platform, epoch, mktime

How can i get count of days since epoch in C++, i know that i should use `mktime` function, but i cant understand how to implement it

Thanks!

Comment: Is the mktime() function required? Depending on what you are doing this for, you might want to consider rolling your own solution. If I were to do this, I would start by writing a program which counts the number of days since the beginning of the year. If you are having trouble with that, back up one more step and write a program which counts the number of days since the beginning of the month. (Note that I'm suggesting simplifying the problem. It's always a good idea to find a small problem which you can easily solve and will help towards solving the larger problem.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date%5Ftime.examples.seconds%5Fsince%5Fepoch

Comment: @Code-Guru, no, mktime is not required

Comment: @Breakdown See my edited comment above which gives some tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying some sample code from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t seconds;

  seconds = time (NULL);
  int daysSinceEpoch = seconds/(60*60*24);
  printf ("%ld days since January 1, 1970", daysSinceEpoch);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dates and times are different things. A day is not just 24 hours, it is the difference between one date and the next, including leap seconds, daylight savings adjustments, etc.

Comment: @bames53 If you just want to know how many days since epoch, this answer is correct. POSIX time ignore leap seconds. With that, a day is always 86400 seconds.

Comment: @Matoran The C and C++ standards don't guarantee POSIX time, though I grant it's a pretty safe assumption. Of course all of these answers including mine already assume the question is asking about the Unix epoch instead of, say, the Windows epoch of 1601-01-01 or the macos core data epoch of 2001-01-01.

Answer (score 3):

Dates aren't easy to work with correctly. The standard library as it stands today doesn't offer the capability to do this correctly. You should use a proper date library, such as boost::date or [Howard Hinnant's `<date>`](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/bloomington/date.html).

With Hinnant's library the code might look something like this:

```
date epoch = year(1970)/jan/day(1); // Assuming you're referring to the traditional Unix epoch (some systems such as Cocoa on OS X use the first day of the millenium, Jan 1, 2001 as their epoch)
days d = date::today() - epoch;
```

Comment: A later version of Howard Hinnant's library is going into C++20.

Answer (score 1):

Begin by getting the current time, with `time(NULL)`. Pass that value to `gmtime`, which gives you back a `tm*`. Read the documentation for `tm`.